# JSON validation shema using Java

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "header": 
      {
         "IssuerID": "000141",
         "AuthenticationID": "e07020c0d040a050a0808099",
         "AuthenticationDateTime": "20151103093035",
         "AuthenticationDateTimeGMT": "20151103093035",
         "Signature": "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"
      },

   "body": 
     {
         "TransactionDateTime": "0151103093035",
         "TransactionID": " SP020110216",
         "IASauthenticationRequestReferenceID": "h0IrqhqBoUpUCiSv17NB0vHvABIUxHGCurJZFzUWdZJz9TxYio",
         "VerificationID": "h0IrqhqBoUpUCiSv17NB0vHvABIUxHGCurJZFzUWdZJz9TxYio ",
         "Acquirer_id": "000014",
         "MerchantName": " Twin Hotel ",
         "CurrencyCodeISO": "360",
         "Amount": "970000.00",
         "CardNumber": " BmaHLuFRg4SaPnaGB07t5fNrHXr/lyOa ",
         "AuthenticationResponseCode": "00",
         "AuthenticationResponseDetails": "Success",
         "ValidityDateTimeExpireGMT": "20151103094035",
         "Expiry_Period": "10"
      }
}
```

How can I validate this json? For example, issuer id must be integer and have min and max values and if someone put headers instead of header it can get result: "json not valid". 
I'm using java and json.org.simple for parsing. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for real schema validation you might want to have a look at http://json-schema.org/. There are validators for most common languages.

Assuming there are classes to represent the above structure you could try to use Java Bean Validation.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would use a deserializer like [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and not a json-schema, since you seem to have integer and dates encoded as string in your json. Thus, in a json-schema you would need to define strange regex. To see how to use jackson and to weigh the pros and cons of each method you can take a look a my blog post here: [Three Ways to Validate JSON in Java](https://guillaumeblanchet.medium.com/three-ways-to-validate-json-in-java-4b38d95ba7c)